# Extract data from Json into Label Text IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

So I am using the pokedex API as a learning curve for IOS and web services,

Here is my didrecivedata when the connection completes

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
    //If the resposne recieved is good the call this function

   // NSLog(@"data is %@", data);

    //NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    //NSLog(@"string is %@", myString);
    //Put data into a string

    NSError *e = nil;

    pokeDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&e];

    NSLog(@"dictionary is %@", pokeDictionary);

}
```

This outputs Json to the console, I can log it into the console like this

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

    // do something with the data

    // receivedData is declared as a method instance elsewhere

    NSLog(@"Succeeded!");

    NSLog(@"The Pokemon's name is %@", pokeDictionary[@"name"]);
    NSLog(@"The Pokemon's attack is %@", pokeDictionary[@"attack"]);
    NSLog(@"The Pokemon's speed is %@", pokeDictionary[@"speed"]);







}
```

However tried to extract Json into text fields like this

```
{

    self.pokemonAttack.text = (@"The Pokemon's speed is %@", pokeDictionary[@"name"]);
    self.pokemonAttack.text = (@"The Pokemon's speed is %@", pokeDictionary[@"attack"]);
    self.pokemonSpeed.text = (@"The Pokemon's speed is %@", pokeDictionary[@"speed"]);



}
```

Error is "expression result unused", I guess my main issue is I am not comfortable with objective-c and just hacking around in IOS. For this I apologise and understand the comments of saying do objective-c courses

If you can point me in the right direction I can continue my trial by fire, I guess I should also be moving to swift soon

Comment: Take a look at [Apple's documentation on string formatting](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html). That should guide you to properly concatenate strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should know that the delegate method `connection:didReceiveData:` may be called multiple times as the connection loads the data incrementally. It may be called once if your returned data is very short, but it will most likely break at some point as you'll end up trying to parse incomplete data.

Regarding the warning you're getting - you just can't format strings like that. You're trying to use string formatting like you're calling NSLog, but the NSLog method does the formatting for you. You need to do something like this:

```
self.pokemonAttack.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"The Pokemon's speed is %@", pokeDictionary[@"speed"]];
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointers :) It does return (null) but at least it puts me on the right path

Comment: Returns null as called in the wrong place, my fault